# Injecting javascript into current page makes an error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm programming a Chrome extension. It opens this HTML in a new window:

Interface.html :

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
  <body style="width: 100px hight: 1000px">
   <div id = "myDiv"> controller</div>
   <button id = "myButton"  >Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

this is the test.js:

```
window.onload = function() 
{
 document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", function()
 {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = "testiTest";
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'inject.js'});

 });


}
```

And this is the inject.js :

```
console.log("some Output");
```

Everything works fine except this line in **test.js**:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: 'inject.js'});
```

The code with should inject a js to the current page (not the Interface.html )

I get this error:

> "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://.../Interface.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (chrome-extension://.../test.js:8:21)"

Comment: You appear to be trying to inject a script into the same page from a script that is already running in that page. I know that you say that you are not wanting to do that, but without supplying a `tabId` to [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) it defaults to the current tab in the current window which is your *interface.html* which you just opened in a new window.

Comment: thanks you were right :) Its seems very hard to get an Tab Id, but it works freat if i just type in a -> "2"

Comment: If you want to know what the active tab is prior to opening the new window, you are probably going to need to determine it prior to opening the new window. Without more code as to when/how/why you are opening the new window, it is difficult to suggest the best way to do this. You may already have access to the ID of the current tab in the code you are using to open the window. On the other hand, you may need to get it through a call to [`tabs.query()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).